# Typescript: using let (best practice)

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm using TypeScript and I'm new using it so I have a question about declaring variables.

When we declare a variable we use `let name: type = value`. Ok, I always assign the type of the variable: if I want a String I declare as `string`, the same with booleans and numbers. I saw the type `any` which make the variable of any type.

The question is: if I declare a variable as a number, is necessary to use `let myNumber: number = 23;`? is necessary to say that the type is a number?

If I don't do, and do a `typeOf(myNumber)` it returns number, but for TypeScript  is `number` or is `any`?

And is best practice to always set the type when assign a value to the variable or it isn't important?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typescript will avoid making variables of type `any`. When you set the option `noImplicityAny` to `true` in your `tsconfig.json`, it will even give you an error when you don't specify a type and Typescript can only set the type to `any`.

Generally speaking, when you specify a type in your `let` as in your example...

```
let myNumber: number = 23;
```

... you set the type *explicitly*. That means you clearly communicate your intent to make this variable a `number`. When  you assign a non-numeric value, you will get an error. There is nothing wrong with declaring *all* your variables with an explicit type, since that only improves the clarity of your code.

The other option is to type your variable *implicitly*. That can only be done when you assign a value to your variable upon declaration:

```
let myNumber = 23;
```

Since you assign a numeric literal to your variable, Typescript can *infer* the type of the variable and will consider it a number. In some cases it is useful to override inferrence, for example for union types:

```
let myNumberOrText: number | string = 23;
```

When you have `noImplicitAny` set to `true`, implicit typings to `any` are forbidden. So...

```
let myAny = { FirstName: "John", LastName: "Doe" };
```

...will cause an error, because it would implicitly type to `any`. The explicit version is still allowed. So you can write...

```
let myAny: any = { FirstName: "John", LastName: "Doe" };
```

...although in Typescript you preferably declare a class or interface and use it for typing (assuming you have declared a type `Person`):

```
let myPerson: Person = { FirstName: "John", LastName: "Doe" };
```

The whole point of Typescript is to introduce static typing to JavaScript. If you declare your variables with type `any`, you will have no advantage from static typing and you can just use plain JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks, I understand. I have a last question: this line `let myNumberOrText: number | string = 23;` you are saying that the type of the variable can be number o string, don't you? So I can initialize it with value `23` but after change the value with `'hello'`?

Comment: @albert: Exactly.